# unix permissions on windows with npm

Tags: windows, node.js, unix, file-permissions, npm

I wrote a node.js module on windows and used npm to publish it.
One of my users uses linux and gave me this feedback:

> The permissions on the directories within your npm package are
>   incorrect.  They don't include the execute permission for the user. This requires to install with admin permissions (sudo) which is not a good idea.

How can I grant these permissions when using npm on windows?

Comment: This question seems to have been asked elsewhere. See this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/npm-/0A6LvPdZ40U